# What map API for android suits my application

Tags: android, google-maps, location-services

I´m making an app that requires the locations of all users that are signed into it and displaying all of their locations to each other on a map.

What tool can you recommend me for the job?

Comment: How about the one the question is tagged with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google maps api for android ([**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro)), and have your app ask for device's current location when user signed on, then post the geo location to a server, finally display the available info using maps marker.

Answer (score 0):

For creating such an app you need to have a PHP server that would first store the geocoordinates of all the users who are currently signed in in a MySQL database. Once you have that part of information you have to convert that database data into JSON object and create your own API/URL which can be requested via an Android client using HTTP. This would populate the maps of all your users with markers displaying their current location.

For implementation details please take a look at the following [tutorial](http://www.developer.com/services/article.php/3862051/Create-Your-Own-Store-Locator-with-Google-Maps-PHP-and-MySQL.htm).